# JSP get data from another session when I switch to another jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, location, href

I have two jsp files login.jsp and index.jsp, login.jsp do an ajax call where after authentication are set values in session with setAttribute('key', value) then a javascript switch to a index.jsp using window.location.href='index.jsp'. index.jsp is calling getAttribute('key') to get the value but the value obtained is not de same which set in login.jsp.

this is the ajax call in login.jsp

```
 75         function login() {
 76             var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
 77             var password = $("#password").val();
 78             var agente = navigator.userAgent;
 79
 80             $.post("app/bd.jsp", {
 81                 funcion: "login",
 82                 "usuario": usuario,
 83                 "password": password,
 84                 "agente": agente
 85             }, function (data) {
 86                 if (data.trim() === "ok") {
 87                     
 88                     window.location.href = 'index.jsp';
 89                 } else {
 90                     $(".has-usuario").addClass("has-error");
 91                     $(".has-password").addClass("has-error");
 92                     $("#mensaje-login").html("Usuario o password invalido");
 93                 }
 94             });
```

After authentication validation, this is executed in bd.jsp when the ajax call is performed:

```
 287 session.setAttribute("clte_code_cliente", 
 resultado.getString("usrw_clte_code_cliente"));
 288 session.setAttribute("clte_nombre_razon", resultado.getString("clte_nombre_razon"));
 289 session.setAttribute("usrw_usuario", resultado.getString("usrw_usuario"));
 290 session.setAttribute("usrw_nombre", resultado.getString("usrw_nombre"));
 291 session.setAttribute("usrw_tipo", resultado.getInt("usrw_tipo"));
 292 session.setAttribute("usrw_id", resultado.getInt("usrw_id"));
```

Then window.location.href = 'index.jsp'; switch to index.jsp when the callback of the ajax call is executed.

Finally in the index.jsp I try to retrieve the session values as:

```
 488 <div class="col-sm-8">
 489   <input type="text"
 490     value="<%=session.getAttribute("clte_code_cliente")%>"
 491     onblur="traerRazonSocial();" class="form-control" id="inputCodigo"
 492     placeholder="Codigo de cliente" required autofocus disabled>
 493 </div>
```

But the information which retrieves session.getAttribute() function is not the correct user information, that information belongs to another user logged before.

thanks!

Comment: please include code you've tried

Comment: I update it, thanks!

Comment: make sure your function that calls `setAttribute` is in the callback of the `ajax` call

Comment: if that doesn't help try console logging the session after you do `session.setAttribute` to make sure the session is actually what you expect. I don't know jsp but does the line `value="<%=session.getAttribute("clte_code_cliente")%>"` with double quotes `"` inside of another double quotes work or do you need to use single quotes?

Comment: It is in the callback and the answer is yes, It works in that way. This was working perfect but for two weeks it started to happen. I'm wondering if this is related to the browser or something on the client side, maybe cache.

Comment: can you put the code that calls `setAttribute` there? I don't see how it is in the callback right now